# Given what happens in Endgame, why doesn't Dormammu come back to attack the universe?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, doctor-strange

Dormammu is the dark being trying to destroy the universe in *Doctor Strange*. Dr Strange uses the Time Stone to keep Dormammu away, this being is referenced in *Avengers: Endgame*, when the Ancient One says she can't lose the protection of her realm and is convinced by the Hulk to release the stone.

Back to the beginning of *Endgame*, once Thanos destroys the Stones, Dormammu should swoop in for the obliteration of the Earth. Why didn't it happen, did Dr Strange destroy Dormammu?

Comment: Maybe Dormammu got snapped, and maybe he will be the next big Marvel villain...

Comment: Dormammu isn't kept from Earth by the time stone, he's kept from Earth by his own word - he banished himself from Earth forever, in exchange for Strange ending the time loop in the Dark Dimension.

Comment: Just because he's evil doesn't mean his word is no good.  See "Lawful Evil".

Comment: This answer is not correct. The sorcerer clearly says `against the forces of darkness` in plural which means there are other threads than Dormammu. Also the sorcerer did not know that Dr.Strange gave away the stone, there is also no indication that she knew about the attack of Dormammu either. This is simply a plot hole.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The Time Stone itself doesn't do anything to protect Earth, in [*Doctor Strange*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Strange_(2016_film)) it is explained that Dormammu is kept out by the three Sanctums (New York, London and Hong Kong) forming a magical shield around the planet:

[image: Sactum Shield]

The Time Stone is a powerful weapon that can be used by the Sorcerer Supreme in their fight against darkness, as Doctor Strange uses it to fight Dormammu after Kaecilius destroys the London and Hong Kong sanctums. The Ancient One is clearly aware of this future battle, and that they will need the Time Stone with them when this happens to win, and she so tells Hulk that she won't give it to him because without it, they'd lose. She then relents when Hulk tells her that the stone will be returned to her within a few seconds due to time travel.

Comment: Actually she doesn't care for Hulk's promises originally, she only relents when Hulk tells her that Stephen Strange gave the time stone away first.

Comment: "The Ancient One is clearly aware of this future battle, and that they will need the Time Stone with them when this happens to win" - she isn't. In "Doctor Strange", she says that she looked into countless futures, but they all end in one specific moment, which we know is before Dormammu invasion. However, she read enough Book of Cagliostro to be aware of dangers lurking out there, and she knows what great power Eye of Agamotto holds. It's easy to put two and two together and figure out Earth has better chances of surviving with Time Stone than without.

Comment: `Earth has better chances of surviving with Time Stone than without` I guess we have a plot for the next Dr. Strange film.

Comment: The first paragraph is helpful but the second one is completely irrelevant, IMO; it would be better to talk about how Dormammu simply agreed to leave Earth alone *in exchange for* Doctor Strange letting him out of the time loop. As he is a being out of time, getting caught in a time loop didn't erase his memory of the previous encounter, causing him no end of mental agony at having to deal with Doctor Strange over and over, forever. There's also no indication he would be aware of the time stone's destruction back in the prime universe.